# Purge PPA after wrong distro in sources.list

Tags: 16.04, package-management, ppa, debian

I accidently added Debian PPA to my sources.list, and upgraded, and now have a broken Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. Debian is launched when I login via grub.

I looked at my sources.list entry and everything has xenial sources except

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free.
```

My other usual entries are of the the form `deb archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main.`

How do I purge the Debian packages and recover Ubuntu desktop?

I tried `sudo ppa-purge -s http://deb.debian.org/debian debian/buster`, but it says no package list for PPA: debian PPA.

Comment: The debian repo isn't added as a PPA which is why you can't use `ppa-purge`.  You should be able to just remove it from `sources.list` or comment it out.

Comment: I have Debian packages installed, and apt-get update also retrieves from Debian. I assume this means it's added?

Comment: You can see what sources are added by looking at the line(s) in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The one you quoted in your question at `debian.org` for `buster` is a Debian repository.  Ubuntu gets packages upstream from Debian, but Ubuntu does not use Debian repositories this way... unless you tell it to, but that can result in a broken system as you've experienced.

Comment: Yep, the problem I have is that it was added, and used in an upgrade. I now woild like to use the purge command to downgrade/remove those packages to the ubuntu default, and I understand ppa-purge could help with that?

Comment: Personally I'd assess the damage, and likely use it as an opportunity to re-install (& thus upgrade) your system (`ubuntu-support-status` will provide some clues!). Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is on it's last months of support, so you'll need to upgrade soon anyway, and default package tools are designed to detect & upgrade to the latest package, so restoring to prior packages is a lot more manual (unless you resort to your backups).

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the Debian repositories from your system, you can remove them from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

- First, back up your current `sources.list`, just in case you make a mistake or things don't go as planned:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
  ```
- Open the file for editing:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- Delete the lines corresponding to Debian sources.  (lines that have `http://deb.debian.org/debian buster`)

  (You could also disable individual lines by commenting them out with a `#` at the beginning of the line.)
- Save changes <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and Exit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Run `sudo apt clean` to clear apt's cache, then `sudo apt update` to update the list of available software.

Comment: I would still need to roll back all the debian software? How would that work? I would have to still do a purge I suppose?

Comment: Not via `ppa-purge`.  If you are aware of specific packages that you believe may be in conflict, you can purge the package in `apt` with `sudo apt purge packagename` but keep in mind that both `purge` and `remove` will also remove dependencies for that package.  Case-dependent this might not be worth the risk

Comment: is not possible to do this via ppa-purge by selecting the debian buster source?

Comment: No. Debian is not a PPA. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas